# What is the purpose of the static member functions in STL's allocator_traits?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, allocator

I am trying to implement an STL-style container class, and I have a question with respect to the use of allocators within my class:

What is the purpose of the static member functions in STL's `allocator_traits`?

Until now, I thought that I am supposed to instantiate the `allocator_type` (probably via some kind of empty base optimization to improve the memory footprint). Thus, I would end up with something like this:

```
struct EmptyBaseOpt : allocator_type
{
  EmptyBaseOpt(const allocator_type & a, allocator_type::const_pointer p)
  : allocator_type(a), prefix_ptr(p) { }

  allocator_type::pointer prefix_ptr;
}

EmptyBaseOpt ebo;
```

And then, I could use the allocator in the following way:

```
allocator_type & alloc = ebo;
alloc.allocate(100, ebo.prefix_ptr);
```

On the other hand, the `allocator_traits` in C++11 seem to imply the following usage:

```
std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::allocate(100, ebo.prefix_ptr);
```

I guess this static `allocate` member function will probably create a temporary ad-hoc instance of `allocator_type` via its default constructor. But this leads to the following questions:

1. What will happen if `allocator_type` is a stateful allocator? Will such allocators be able to keep their state if I use the static member functions in `allocator_traits` instead of calling the non-static methods from an instance of `allocator_type`?
2. Why should I instantiate `allocator_type` at all and bother with stuff like EBO if I can directly use the static member functions in `allocator_traits` instead?
3. As stated before, my understanding is that any class-like template parameters should be instantiated inside my container class in order to allow for stateful versions of these parameters. Is this understanding correct, and how does it fit with the static member functions in `allocator_traits`?

Comment: FWIW, there's no `allocator_traits` template in the STL. It's part of C++11's standard library, but that [is not the STL](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/it-is-not-called-the-stl-mmkay/).

Comment: @Angew: You are right. I have used the terms too sloppy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have missed the fact that all the static member functions in `allocator_traits` take `Alloc &` as the first parameter. That is, they use an object of the allocator type to do their work.

The reason for this policy of "access an allocator through `allocator_traits` only" is that some members of `allocator_traits` provide a default implementation of an allocator operation if one is not provided by the allocator type itself. This applies to all members which were added to the allocator requirements in C++11 and were not present in C++03. An example is `construct`, which will call the placement `new` operator `::new` if the allocator type does not provide a suitable `construct` function. These defaults thus allow allocators written for C++03 to function unchanged with a C++11 container.

Additionally, using `allocator_traits` allows for more customisability. `allocator_traits` can be specified for a particular allocator class and the trait functions can be implemented by different calls on the `Alloc &` parameter.

So your assumption on instantiating the `allocator_type` is correct. The difference is that you're not supposed to call its member functions directly (because they might not exist), but through the static accessors in `allocator_traits`.

Comment: The primary purpose is to provide the defaults, **not** customisability. The standard containers have preconditions that the `allocator_type` meets the Allocator requirements, which means (among other things) it **must** have an `allocate` member, so your example of a 3rd-party class with a different interface being used as an allocator is incorrect. That wouldn't be valid. `allocator_traits` provides defaults for the propagation traits and variadic `construct` function, which C++03 allocators don't have.

Comment: @Angew: Thanks a lot. Now I think I understand: So I use the `allocator_type` directly only for instantiation, but all the typedefs and function calls should be wrapped via the `allocator_traits`, right?

Comment: @MAA1612, yes, exactly

Answer (score 6):

> On the other hand, the allocator_traits in C++11 seem to imply the following usage:
>
> ```
> std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::allocate(100, ebo.prefix_ptr);
> ```

No, you're missing the most important argument to that function call: the allocator.

> I guess this static allocate member function will probably create a temporary ad-hoc instance of allocator_type via its default constructor.

No, because you pass an allocator argument to the function.

> What will happen if allocator_type is a stateful allocator?

It works fine, because you pass that stateful allocator as an argument to the functions that use it.

> Why should I instantiate allocator_type at all and bother with stuff like EBO if I can directly use the static member functions in allocator_traits instead?

Because you can't use them instead.

> As stated before, my understanding is that any class-like template parameters should be instantiated inside my container class in order to allow for stateful versions of these parameters. Is this understanding correct, and how does it fit with the static member functions in allocator_traits?

Yes, your understanding is correct, and it fits fine with `allocator_traits` if you use it properly.

The point of `allocator_traits` is to provide sensible defaults for most of the Allocator interface. This has two purposes:

- firstly it is simpler to define an allocator in C++11 (you only need to provide `value_type`, `allocate`, `deallocate`, a template constructor for re-binding the allocator and `operator==` and `operator!=`) so writing simple custom allocators now is much simpler.
- secondly it allows existing allocators that only meet the C++03 allocator requirements to be used by C++11 containers. C++03 allocators do not define the nested members such as `propagate_on_container_swap` that C++11 containers look for, or the new variadic `construct(pointer, Args&&...)` member that allows objects to be constructed with any arguments, not just copy constructed (which is what allows `emplace` to work). So by wrapping use of allocators in `allocator_traits` most of the Allocator interface is given sensible defaults, so that existing C++03 code using a custom allocator with a container such as `std::vector` won't suddenly fail to build if recompiled using C++11. The `std::vector` implementation only uses the new members through the `allocator_traits` type and so it doesn't matter that the custom allocator wasn't updated to provide all the new members that are part of the C++11 Allocator requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote, because I am lacking the required reputation. Btw: Should my custom container evaluate `propagate_on_container_swap` etc. as well, or is that only required for std containers in order to conform to the std behavior?

Comment: If you want to fully support stateful allocators then you need to decide what happens to the container under assignment and swap. You can either make up your own set of rules, or follow the same design as the standard containers. See http://accu.org/content/conf2012/JonathanWakely-CXX11_allocators.pdf for some notes on how the propagation traits are used.